# Leverage variable values/types to rename columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-management

I have searched stackoverflow for an answer to this question but have had no luck so far. My request:

For a simple dataframe:

```
# create dummy data.frame
d <- data.frame(var1 = as.character(1:5), 
                var2 = factor(letters[1:5]), 
                var3 = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                var4 = rep("<div class='The mink cat'< /p>'",5))
```

How do I go about renaming the variables based on the variable type / string content without referencing the original column name (e.g., d[,1] or var1)?

Rename var1-var3 to character, factor and numeric given by the value type in each variable.

Rename var4 as 'mink' by a search of the variable values and leveraging part of the string: 'the mink cat'.

Comment: DId you meant `nm1 <- sapply(d, class);
 names(d)[1:3] <- nm1[1:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we commented earlier, the solution would be to find the `class` of the columns with `sapply`, then name the columns with that object ('nm1') and finally, `unlist` the first row, get the index of columns that have 'mink' and assign the column names to 'mink'

```
nm1 <- sapply(d, class)
names(d) <- nm1
names(d)[grep("mink", unlist(d[1,]))] <- "mink"
d
#  character factor integer                            mink
#1         1      a       1 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
#2         2      b       2 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
#3         3      c       3 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
#4         4      d       4 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
#5         5      e       5 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the purrr library for a more simplified code

```
library(purrr)
colnames(d) <- map_chr(d, class)

d

  character factor integer                       character
1         1      a       1 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
2         2      b       2 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
3         3      c       3 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
4         4      d       4 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
5         5      e       5 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
colnames(d) = lapply(d,class)
colnames(d)[sapply(d, function(x) any(grepl("cat",x)))] = "mink"
```

Output:

```
  character factor integer                            mink
1         1      a       1 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
2         2      b       2 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
3         3      c       3 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
4         4      d       4 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
5         5      e       5 <div class='The mink cat'< /p>'
```

Where the last column is renamed to 'mink', since it contains 'mink'.